# .htaccess is not working on Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS

Tags: 16.04, apache2, php, .htaccess

I want to use .htaccess for rewriting of php web pages. Or in a simple way "I don't want to use .php extension" to access any web page.

.htaccess file (Ubuntu 14) which was working perfectly:

```
RewriteEngine on
#remove the need for .php extention
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

Same .htaccess file is not working after upgrade of AWS which is now in Ubuntu 16.04. I tried everything like changing the permission, enabling the rewrite mode, changing the config file Directory property from 'AllowOverride None' to 'AllowOverride All'.

After some sort of experiment I found to be amend the above .htaccess file as below and it worked fine. But here it always allow to access only given php page. But I don't want to be specific with any given php page. I tried writing regexp as well but didn't work. And it always redirect to the given page only.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c><
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Can someone help me on this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I see a `>` syntax error in the `IfModule` code

Answer (score 4):

I was facing same problem, here is solution for **ubuntu and apache**

First enable module rewrite:

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

And restart apache

```
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

Now edit for directory level

```
sudo vim /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf
```

add these lines at end

```
<Directory /var/www/html>
    AllowOverride All
 </Directory>
```

and restart apache again.

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 2):

I found this example that should do the trick:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule !.*\.php$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [QSA,L]
```

Source:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4026021/remove-php-extension-with-htaccess

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1992183/how-to-hide-the-html-extension-with-apache-mod-rewrite

Answer (score 1):

*Translation adapted from Google Translate*

Greetings I had the same problem in a VPS that I contracted with Ubuntu 16.04

I wanted to deploy an app made in Angular 8 with Apache, I put the `.htaccess` in the folder of my Angular project and it did not work, I activated the a2enmod rewrite it restarted and neither.

I managed to fix it by doing these simple steps, which BSB comments

**1)** run the command:
`sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf`

**2)** Type `AllowOverride All` at the end of the `000-default.conf file` that we just opened in console

Obviously it should be before the label

**3)** Restart the Server

---- **Optional** -----

- Apart from this, in my `index.html` file of my Angular project, in the base tag put the name

`base href = "/ name /"`

And in the `.htaccess` file too, at the end, place

```
RewriteRule ^ /name/index.html
```

And ready this will work perfectly

**----------**

Saludos tenia el mismo problema en un VPS que contraté con Ubuntu 16.04

Quería desplegar una app hecha en Angular 8 con Apache, coloqué el .htaccess en la carpeta de mi proyecto Angular y no funcionaba, activé el a2enmod rewrite reiniciaba y tampoco.

Logré solucionarlo haciendo estos sencillos pasos, que comenta BSB

1. sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf 2. Colocar al final del archivo 000-default.conf que acabamos de abrir en consola

AllowOverride All

Obviamente debe ser antes de la etiqueta

3. Reiniciamos el Servidor listo

---- Opcional -----

```
A parte de esto en mi archivo index.html de mi proyecto Angular en la etiqueta base coloque un nombre, de esta manera
```

base href="/nombre/"

```
Y en el archivo .htaccess también, al final colocar
```

RewriteRule ^ /nombre/index.html

Y listo esto funcionará perfectamente

Answer (score 0):

`sudo vim /etc/apache2/apache2.conf`

edit AllowOverride None to “All”

<Directory /var/www/>

```
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks

    AllowOverride All

    Require all granted
```

then run these commands

`sudo a2enmod rewrite`

`sudo systemctl restart apache2.service`

try this link if needed

https://www.tutsmake.com/how-to-mod_rewrite-enable-in-apache-ubuntu-18-04/

https://www.keycdn.com/support/htaccess-not-working